# PHP/SQL/Mysql/phpmyadmin - Foreign Keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm building a shop for school purposes. I have finished my shop but i didn't joined tables and used foreign keys (requirement) because i forgot..

I have a newbie 'question' about foreign keys.

PRODUCTS RATING TABLE:

```
rate_id (id of the rate),
rate, (stars 0 to 5)
comment (user input textarea),
user_id (id of the user who commented the product),
product_id (id of the product that was commented)
```

USERS TABLE:

```
`id` (id of the user),
`email` (email of the user),
`name` (name of the user),
`age`,
`username`,
`password`,
`profile_pic`,
`role` (ADMIN/USER)´
```

When i enter a comment on X product (if (isset($_POST['comment_rating])):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_id'");
```

and then later:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products_rating (rate, comment, user_id, product_id) 
            VALUES ('$rate_text', '$comment', '$user_id', '$product_id');
```

FINAL: What i want to know is, what do i need to change in my code if i add a foreign key? And should i add a foreign key in this particular case? I must interligate all tables, and I don't understand much about joins / foreign keys. If i wasn't clear let me know. Thank you for you help!

Comment: I'm confused. Are you looking for the syntax for creating foriegn keys? Or the best columns on which to create them? Or how joins work?

Comment: Im looking for what to change in my insert and the best columns on with to create them.

Comment: In theory nothing different to insert them, assuming `user_id` and `product_id` are valid (they have parent keys in the appropriate tables). In terms of which columns, no one can answer that without your schema and the relationship between them.

Comment: As @kchason said, your SQL doesn't change after you've added foreign key relationships. You will want to make sure you are checking for errors since a broken relationship may lead to an error during the insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of a foreign key is pretty straightforward.

In the `products_rating` table, we are storing a value for `user_id`.

And the value that we stored there is a value of `id` column from a row in the `user` table.  This establishes a *relationship* between the row in `products_rating` an a row in `user`.

We could get the name and email address of the user that left a product rating

```
SELECT u.name
     , u.email
     , r.rate
     , r.comment
  FROM product_rating r
  JOIN user u 
    ON u.id = r.user_id 
 WHERE ...
```

---

A `FOREIGN KEY` is a *constraint* that implements a rule. The rule we want to implement is that we want to allow only *valid* `user.id` values to be stored in `product_rating.user_id`.

For example, if we attempt to store a value of '42' in the `product_rating.user_id` column, the database is going to check that the value '42' appears in a row in the `user` table (in the `id`) column.

The syntax that we use to implement that *constraint* would be on the `product_rating` table:

```
ALTER TABLE `product_rating` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT                  -- we are adding a constraint 
  `FK_product_rating_user`        -- the name we assign to the constraint
  FOREIGN KEY                     -- the type of constraint 
  (`user_id`)                     -- the column(s) in this table 
  REFERENCES                      -- refer to 
  `user`                          -- the name of the "foreign" table
  (`id`)                          -- the column(s) in the "foreign" table
```

We can add some additional configuration that affects behavior...

```
  ON DELETE RESTRICT 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

This implements a rule... if we attempt to assign a value to `user_id` column in this table, and that value is not found in a row in `user` table `id` column, an error is thrown, and the statement fails.

This rule also says that if we attempt to remove a row from `user`, if there are any rows in `product_rating` that have a `user_id` value that matches the `id` value of the row we're deleting, an error is thrown, and the statement fails.

The rule also says that we update a row in `user`, and assign a new value to the `id` column, than any rows in `product_rating` that have a `user_id` value that matches the old `id` value will be updated, to assign the new `id` value to the `user_id` column... preserving the *relationship* between the rows.

Also note that this implies a "one-to-many" relationship. A user can be related to zero, one or more `product_rating`. A `product_rating` is associated with *one* `user`. (If the `user_id` column allows for NULL values to be stored, a NULL value represents that the row in `product_rating` is *not* associated with any user.)

That's just a rough overview of `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

The basic idea is that we establish a *relationship* between rows by storing a common value. In the example we use, a common value of '42' in the `id` column of a row in the `user` table,  and in the `user_id` column of one (or more) row(s) in the `product rating` table.

With no foreign key constraint defined, the database allows us to store any value in the `user_id` column. We could store '43' or '8670', and it doesn't matter if those values appear in `user.id` or not.

The foreign key we defined *constrains* (restricts) what values we can store in the `user_id` column. When we attempt to add or modify a row in `product_rating`, the database checks the value of the `user_id` column, and if a non-NULL value doesn't reference a row in `user`, an error is raised.

---

Note that the foreign key constraint does not cause the `user_id` column to be automatically populated. If we want to establish a relationship to a row in `user`, we have to supply a value for `user_id`.